# PHP Delete item from database not working

Tags: php, mysql, plesk

I've a little script for deleting certificates by id number from my database but this is not working fine.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $conn = mysqli_connect(host, db_user, db_pass, db);
    $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
    $query = "DELETE FROM cert_details where certid = ". mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $r = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    mysqli_close($conn);
    header('location: dashboard.php');

}
else{
    header("location: index.php");
} ?>
```

This is what I am doing at HTML side

`echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"deletecert.php?id=$certidd\" onSubmit=\"return confirm('Are you sure?')\">";
echo "<button name=\"del\" value=\"Delete\" type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-danger\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash\"></i></button>";
echo "</form>";`

This is having trouble on the remote hosting, but not on my local server.

Comment: No need to use `htmlspecialchars` and `mysql_real_escape_string`. Just use the latter, although as you're using mysqli you should be using `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead. Not sure if `host`, `db_user` etc. needs to have a $ in front? Can you share your `config.php`? (change passwords if needed)

Comment: @rjdown Here is the config.php

`<?php
 /*
  Configuration of Database
 */
 define('db_user', 'phcoa');
 define('db_pass', '******');
 define('db', 'certificates');
 define('host', 'localhost');
?>`

Comment: Thanks, that looks ok then.

Comment: Maybe you're asking for something that doesn't exist. Why don't you throw a var_dump of the id in every step? ($_GET['id'], htmlspecialchars and mysqli_real_escape_string) and also check `mysqli_error()` while you're at it.

Comment: maybe some mysql error trapping. Do you just plow forward assuming you are even connected or bother to look at error messages? The answer to those two questions are Yes and No, respectively

Comment: Query seems fine, even the errors I mentioned above shouldn't make this fail. Try `echo $query;`, seems like the  ID is not getting passed.

Comment: It's working perfectly on localhost. I just don't get if what the hell is wrong?

Comment: note, you are using both `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions.   This can cause some servers to break.  Use `mysql_` only (and also because `mysql_` is deprecated)

Comment: also you need to verify if you are actually connecting to the database.  Se the answer to this question below  on how to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<?php
session_start();
require "./config.php";

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    $mysqli = new mysqli(host, db_user, db_pass, db);

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        die("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
    $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM cert_details where certid = ". $mysqli->real_escape_string($id));
    mysqli->close();

    header('location: ./dashboard.php');

}else{
    header("location: ./index.php");
}
?>
```